# Assessing distribution of a Likert scales

Tags: variance, likert, scales, measurement

I am looking to analyse Likert scales, and want to assess whether there is 'sufficient variation' along the scale [i.e. that the majority of respondents are not 'clumped together' or a particular value, such as in the middle responding 3, or 'to some extent']

Are there are any standard pre-analysis tests for gauging whether there is 'sufficient' variance in the responses to a Likert scale - or norms over what the variance of the scale should be. [it feels to me like it should be something that people care about when assessing scales, but I havn't found much on it].

I am ultimately looking to have a sentance in the paper i am writing which says something to the effect of "there was sufficient variance in the scale, responses were not group on a particular value". [or something to that effect]

Comment: Sufficient for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no such thing as sufficient variance or lack of it in a survey with Likert scales. You are essentially asking people their opinions/feelings. 
For broad questions or ones touching controversial subjects the answers may show a bigger variance (always depending on your sample), for other questions the variance could be small representing a wide held liking, opinion or feeling.